# Programming language for configuration

Tags: java, scala, configuration, programming-languages

I need a configuration language with a little code. I'm trying to use scala. Can I write in Scala or in other JVM language something like

```
... = car() {
    title = "Experimental Car"
    engine = dieselEngine() {
        capacity = 1.9
    }
}
```

instead of

```
val c = car()
c.title = "Experimental Car"
c.engine = c.dieselEngine()
c.engine.capacity = 1.9
```

It is important, that dieselEngine is method on car.

Comment: what are those dots? why you need something like that? if you need configuration, won't be better just read it from file?

Comment: Very strange that this completely legitimate question is downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Scala case classes provide exactly what you need:

```
case class Car(title: String, engine: Engine)

// A marker trait and several implementations
sealed trait Engine
case class DieselEngine(capacity: Double) extends Engine
case class ElectricEngine(capacity: Int) extends Engine

val c = Car(
  title = "Experimental car",
  engine = DieselEngine(capacity = 1.9)
)
```

See [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Try Groovy method `with`:

```
... = new Car().with {
  title = "Experimental Car"
  engine = dieselEngine().with {
    capacity = 1.9
    return this
  }
  return this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also supported nicely by [Builders](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Builders) in the Groovy language. You'd have syntax

```
car {
    title: "Experimental Car"
    engine: dieselEngine {
        capacity: 1.9
    }
}
```